# Trouble connecting straight segments with a smooth curve

Tags: inkscape, shapes, bezier-curve

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to create a capital 'E' like the first image (without the text filling up the body).

The second image is what I have so far. I'm having trouble specifically with creating a curve that looks smooth enough to connect the vertical rectangle with the horizontal one.

I've recently started using Inkscape, and am a beginner, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you started off with a Union of two rectangles with a sharp corner at the serif, you can turn the corner node into a Symmetric node. Then hold down CTRL to restrict the angle of the Bézier handles so they are upright, then move the node down using the arrow keys. Then you can drag the Bézier handle upwards (while holding CTRL) to make a nice smooth curve.

For example:

[image]

Another possibility is to also extend the Bézier handle on the other corner of the serif a little, which will also help with the smoothing, so then you will have two handles controlling the curve.

For example:

[image]